# Sampling from a distribution characterized by its characteristic function

Tags: distributions, sampling, simulation, characteristic-function

Consider the following measure:
$$d\nu (x)=\mathbb 1_{(0,1)} (x) \frac 1 {x^{2}}$$
Now, define $X$ with characteristic function given by:
$$\varphi_{X}(t)= \exp\left\{ \int_{\mathbb R} [e^{itx}-1 - itx] d \nu(x) \right\}$$

I would like to know how I can proceed to take an iid sample of size $N$ according to the same distribution as $X$.  I tried to implement it in R, but to be honest I didn't even know how to start.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?